# How Unsafe.AsPointer<T>(ref T value) works?

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe

In C# you're not suppose to be able to create pointer to managed types but with this API you are able to, using `Unsafe.AsPointer<T>`.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/

I see the source code using ILSpy and I saw this:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
[System.Runtime.Versioning.NonVersionable]
public unsafe static void* AsPointer<T>(ref T value)
{
    return &value;
}
```

Also in other similar API:

```
//Unity.Collections.LowLevel.Unsafe.UnsafeUtility
public unsafe static T ReadArrayElement<T>(void* source, int index)
{
    return *(T*)((byte*)source + index * sizeof(T));
}
```

How this works and how is possible to replicate that behaviour?

Comment: You can create & use pointers in C# just fine. All you need to do is enable unsafe code. This has been part of the language for a very long time.

Comment: Yes, but you can't create pointers to managed types or get a warning "Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type", when I try to use any of those methods I get that warning.

Comment: Why would you need a pointer to a managed type? You can only read / change the bytes of primitive types - managed types are just collections of primitive types.

Comment: @xxbbcc The point is that you can't create a generic method like the shown `AsPointer<T>` even if you enable unsafe code. C# compiler is working differently for MSFT code :)

Comment: @IvanStoev Sure but `AsPointer` for a managed type _is already_ there for you, no need to create that. Managed types do not guarantee to follow a particular memory layout so getting a pointer to a managed instance is a very risky thing to do anyway.

Comment: @xxbbcc Again I think you (and close voters) are missing the point. OP is not asking whether it's good or bad, or how to use the system provided methods, all they ask **how** is that possible some system classes to contain a non valid C# code.

Comment: @IvanStoev It was probably never written in C# in the first place. It is _decompiled into C#_ so it seems like it's C# code but it was either done in C++ or (more likely) ILAsm.

Comment: That method was not done in C# in the first place: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/a07f0c8d4efcb384c2d831c2582645098922d3ca/src/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/src/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.il#L145-L152

Comment: @xxbbcc Indeed. And probably that should be the answer to OP question rather than general comments :)

Comment: @IvanStoev There you go. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code in question is not valid C# code and was probably not written in C# in the first place. What you see is ILSpy's C# representation of the underlying code - the C# syntax is capable of representing this because it's just a compiler rule that says you can't get a pointer to a managed type.

My guess (I don't know this for a fact) that the code in question was written in IL in the first place - if you decompile it to IL, you can see that it's a trivial bit:

```
.method public hidebysig static 
    void* AsPointer<T> (
        !!T& 'value'
    ) cil managed flag(0100) 
{
    .custom instance void 
        System.Runtime.Versioning.NonVersionableAttribute::.ctor() = (
        01 00 00 00
    )
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2190
    // Code size 3 (0x3)
    .maxstack 1

    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: conv.u
    IL_0002: ret
} // end of method Unsafe::AsPointer
```

(This is from System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll.)

The managed instance is loaded onto the stack and then it's simply returned as an unsigned pointer value.

If you want to recreate this behavior, you can - simply write your DLL in IL and compile it, then reference it from any other .NET language that supports pointers.